# Using FRIEND_TEST to test private functions of a class in another namespace

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm trying to use GTest's `FRIEND_TEST()` macro to enable testing of some private functions from another namespace. However, I can't get past some errors, though I must be missing something simple.

I have `Tests.cpp` where I would like to test private functionality of `MyClass`:

```
namespace a::b::tests 
{

  class MyTests : public ::testing::Test { ... };

  TEST_F(MyTests, Test1)
  {
    // Test private functions of MyClass instance from MyClass.cpp
    ...
  }

}
```

In `MyClass.h`, implemented in `MyClass.cpp`, I have:

```
namespace a::b
{
  class MyTests_Test1_Test; // Forward declaration.

  class MyClass
  {
    private:
      FRIEND_TEST(a::b::tests::MyTests, Test1);   
      ...
  };
}
```

However, this fails with compile-time errors `'a::b::tests' has not been declared` and  `error: friend declaration does not name a class or function`.

If I try to forward-declare the namespace by adding `using a::b::tests;` in `MyClass.h`, the error remains.

How can I properly make `MyTests` a friend class of `MyClass` here?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my apologies for the mistake, could you please delete your comment for code anonymity/non-disclosure reasons? I updated the post for consistency.

Comment: ok, its easiest to create a new seperate toy project containing the mcve that you want to post here. In the best case it can be compiled to reproduce the same error as the real code (and does not contain confidentials)

Comment: Offtopic: IMO use of `FRIEND_TEST()` makes test entangled with implementation detail. This means you can't refactor code without refactoring tests. That is why I never use `FRIEND_TEST()`.

Comment: @MarekR I was expecting such a comment. In principle, I tend to agree, but sometimes as developers we get tasked with working/extending something already put in place in a specific way, and have to use non-ideal solutions.

Comment: you missed `tests` namespace in forward declaration, so simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to do forward declarations like this, in `MyClass.h`:

```
namespace a::b::tests
{
    class MyTests;
    class MyTests_Test1_Test;
}

namespace a::b 
{
  class MyClass
  {
    private:
      FRIEND_TEST(a::b::tests::MyTests, Test1);   
      ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Mmm, isn't this what i suggested in my answer? I said it for `MyTests` so it will also apply to other classes as well. Just because the class name has changed from `MyTests` to `MyTests_Test1_Test` doesn't make it a completely different thing. It is the same concept. Just saying/mentioning this with no hard feelings. For example, if in future you add some other class say named `MyTestsClass3` then you would have to do the same for that also. Doing that won't make it anything different from what i already suggested.

Comment: The class name didn't change: it's that I had to explicitly move the MyTests_Test1_Test forward declaration inside the above namespace: it wouldn't work when declared inside MyClass. So this was the crucial detail.

Comment: No, the reason i am objecting is that your original question only mentioned one error which was related to `MyTests` so there was no way i could've predicted that you also wanted to befriend class `MyTests_Test1` also. Moreover, you specifically asked in your question: **"How can I properly make `MyTests` a friend class of `MyClass` here?"**. See in the above quoted text from your question you only asked about befriending `MyTests` and not `MyTests_Test1`so i only provided the answer for `MyTests`. If you were to ask about befriending `MyTests_Test1` then i would have provided for that also.

Comment: I included the errors produced by the compiler initially in the original question. The error that you mention was not there at that point. Befriending MyTests_Test1_Test  was indeed not something that I attempted to do, but fwd-declaring it was a part of the solution. You seem to be suggesting that this is some missing class that I knew about but omitted in my question: it's not. From my understanding, it's the name that GTest produces internally for the test class in question, and I wasn't aware I'm supposed to declare it in such a manner beforehand.

Comment: What i am saying is that this particular question is concerned only with: *"How can I properly make `MyTests` a friend class of `MyClass` here?"*. Any follow-up question related to any follow-up errors that you get should be asked as a separate question or as a comment. This means *"fwd-declaring it was a part of the solution"* is incorrect as it has nothing to do with the actual question being asked which was about `MyTests` and there was no mention of the error related to(or due to) `MyTests_Test1` in the original question. So this is not part of the solution(to the original question).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **forward declaration** for `a::b::tests::MyTests` because you've implemented it in a source file `Tests.cpp` which is different from the header file `MyClass.h` and at the point where you've written  `FRIEND_TEST(a::b::tests::MyTests, Test1);` the compiler doesn't know that there is a class `a::b::tests::MyTests`.

So to **solve** this add this in your header file `MyClass.h`:

**MyClass.h**

```
namespace a::b::tests 
{
//-------------v-------------->note only a declaration and not a definition
  class MyTests;//added this forward declaration
}
////////////////////////////
//now we can write the below code exactly as before since we have a forward declaration for a::b::tests::MyTests

namespace a::b
{
  class MyTests_Test1_Test; 

  class MyClass
  {
    private:
      FRIEND_TEST(a::b::tests::MyTests, Test1);   
      ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately like my other forward-declaration attempts this one doesn't work either: I get `error: 'MyTests_Test1_Test' in namespace 'a::b::tests' does not name a type`, although the spelling is clearly correct.

Comment: @w128 This is a different error than the one you mentioned in your original question. The original error  is gone/solved due to the forward declaration that i suggested in my answer. Now the next error that you're getting is related to `MyTests_Test1_Test`. And since there isn't much information about `MyTests_Test1_Test` i can't say much about this next error. Also make sure that in the forward declaration of `MyTests_Test1_Test` you have qualified it with `tests::` or `a::b::tests`. This may solve this new error.

Comment: @ Anoop Rana indeed, you got me on the right track either way. I will post the solution that worked shortly. I'm upvoting your answer.